# Chow Breakpoint-Test in R for VAR-Models

Tags: r, var

do you know any package which includes a Chow-Breakpoint Test in R for Vectorautoregressive Models? I already looked into vars, tseries, strucchange (If I understand the documentation correct, then there is just a test for the univariate case), but I don't find anything useful.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Unfortunately package requests (in R or other languages) are not on-topic here - have a look at our [help/on-topic] to get a feel for what questions are within the scope of the site.

Comment: In `vars` there is the function `stability()` that conducts equation-wise structural change tests based on the `strucchange` package. This just interfaces the fluctuation-type structural change tests but you could easily adapt the code to perform Chow tests or - probably better - supF (or supChow) tests. But in all cases the tests would be equation-wise.